# Pattern for sharing SQLiteCursorLoader object between activities

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, commonsware-cwac

Default Android `CursorLoader` uses `ContentProvider` and knows about all *inserts, updates*, ... `SQLiteCursorLoader` doesn't know, but I'm curious about the best pattern for sharing *SQLiteCursorLoader* object between activities. Is it possible at all?

Comment: can you please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950015/passing-a-cursor-to-an-activity/8456148#8456148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not share loaders, period, whether it is `SQLiteCursorLoader`, `CursorLoader`, or any other `Loader`. They are only for use by the activity/fragment that created them.